# How to asyncrhonously execute a MSSQL stored procedure without blocking PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, asynchronous, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

We have a PHP application that needs to execute some routines in MSSQL, using sqlsrv driver.

We're developing a solution that, using AJAX, will monitor that execution and keep user updated of the progress.

Currently it's implemented in a stored procedure. But when PHP executes it, it stays blocked until a time out exception is thrown. We need PHP to execute it and immediately return, leaving the SP running.

Is there any option that allows `sqlsrv_query()` or another function to execute asynchronously?

Comment: The driver needs to support asynchronous execution of queries. The only one I'm aware of which supports this is MySQLi with native driver.

Comment: MySQLi? Why should one use driver for MySQL to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: i dont know php but i would look for threading and call this stored proc in its own thread. But as i said, i dont know if php supports threading

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried sp_async_executed which is available in sql-server 2008+?